# Writing a string instead of true/false for a checkbox in VBA?

Tags: string, vba, function, checkbox, subroutine

I have been trying to output a string when a checkbox is clicked in excel. The checkboxes are currently linked to a separate page in the work book. The code I am writing so far is:

```
Private Sub Rollout()

If Rollout.Value = True Then
Range(D11, [D11]).Value = "Roll-Out"
Else
Range(D11, [D11]).Value = "No Roll-Out Service"
End If

End Sub
```

Rollout() is the Macro assigned to the checkbox. The cell on the page that I want the string to output is D11.

I'm pretty new to VBA so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct command window or if I need to write a function and then call it in the sub?

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 Worksheets("AppropriateWorksheetName").Range("D11").Value = "No Roll-Out Service"
```

> I'm pretty new to VBA so I'm not sure if I'm using the correct command window or if I need to write a function and then call it in the sub?

The command window writes a function; they both do the same thing, it's just that the command window is easier to use but has more limited functionality. If you are just learning, the command window is fine